# Style line height for HTML emails in Outlook Web App

Tags: html, outlook, html-email, outlook-web-app

I have been working on a HTML email and have tried everything to get the `line-height` to display properly in Microsoft Outlook Web App. I've tried `!important` on my inline styles, using `.ExternalClass * {line-height: 100%}` in the document head, wrapping text in a span with an `inline line-height` style, having `line-height` on the parent `td` and also a `span`.

If anyone can help it be much appreciated!

Below is an example of an area of my current text in a td.

```
<td pardot-region="articleContent1a" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 25px; text-align: left; color: #7f7f7f;" valign="top">
  Yesterday, Krissy posted about six things you should consider when performing a high-level user experience (UX) audit of a website. While UX is a crucial component of measuring a website’s success, it’s only part of the equation.</td>
```

I've also tried adding to the td mso-line-height-rule: exactly.

Comment: maybe you could add one or two versions of your code, what you have tried *exactly*. Might be helpful for others to see the problem

Answer (score 4):

I know it's a past issue, but I don't see an accepted answer. Do you have a jsfiddle link to see your code?

You did say you set the embedded CSS override to 100%; try setting it to 112%:

`.ExternalClass * { line-height:112%; }`

Outlook Webmail won't have the exact line-heights you want, but it does override the one that Webmail adds in.

Other possibilities:

- Line heights should be specified in the table cell `<td>` and not any inline tags (like `<span>`).
- The order you use `mso-line-height-rule:exactly` is important - the line height should be declared immediately after mso-line-height-rule:

  `<td style="font-size:1em;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;line-height:1.3em;">`
- Last option, put each line of text in its own table row/table cell, and control line-height by using padding in each row via the table cell.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Triple up on your line-height (body, td and spans). Be sure to add style for your font in every td or span that contains text. in spite of what guides tell you, it's my professional experience that you CAN better use 'span' instead of 'p'.

use conditional styling for Outlook using:

```
table {
font-size:1px;
mso-line-height-alt:0;
line-height:0;
mso-margin-top-alt:1px;
}
```

Off course; your email should be designed using tables... But that is common practice.

Comment: I forgot to mention the global CSS for Outlook.com: 
    .ExternalClass * {line-height: 100%;}

Comment: Sorry, I'm late but I appreciate this info Jazper. I'm going to try it in the next email template I work on. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this CSS support for email guide](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/), `line-height` is ignored on table cells for Outlook.com - they suggest trying it on `p` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but no luck :/

Comment: You should never, ever, use `p` tags because they add extra spacing in certain email clients, namely Outlook.